# Windows server ipv6 dhcp

Tags: ipv6, windows-server-2019, dhcp-server

I'm sorry but i'm stuck since a lot of time now.

I tried to make a scope for ipv6 at my home, i have a windows server 2019 machine that manages a lot of things.

I don't understand why but i can't have something good, my router from my provider seems to give all ipv6 even when  i (think) disable ipv6 dhcp (it's not clear, this box has more than 10 years).

I tried with fc and fd ranges, my  server uses a static ip like for ipv4... everything is ok for ipv4 but it don't work at all with ipv6

Comment: Why do you need IPv6 for a home network? What IPv6 settings have you set in the router (a screenshot will be helpful)?

Comment: My own router allows me to have IPv6 or IPv4 for my internal LAN. That would be the proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: Read the question please.